# DMX4LINUX drivers wont build properly

Tags: drivers, build, makefile

I am currently troubleshooting a situation in which I am trying to build drivers for ENTECC'S Open DMX to usb converter. I am currently building this on  a Raspberry Pi 3, using the pre release version of the kernel(4.19.58-v7+). Configuration of the software is successful, however, after executing the make command It returns the following output:

https://pastebin.com/BWjBv37C

The file that seems to be returning the error is drivers/dmxdev/Makefile, as stated in the line:

`make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/linux-246113692edbef9a438b31ab2dd0172a30ed5eb2'
scripts/Makefile.build:50: *** CFLAGS was changed in "/home/pi/dmx4linux-2.6.1/drivers/dmxdev/Makefile". Fix it to use ccflags-y.  Stop.`

I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to the makefile build process so please any help is appreciated, Thanks!